# Unix process writing to a file descriptor ends while the children are still alive (perl)

Tags: perl, unix, exec, fork, pipe

So I have the following code, the problem is that it exits before all the child processes (sort/gzip) are done. How can I instruct Perl to wait for all the descendent processes ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use strict;
use warnings;

sub systemBash {
  my $cmd = shift;
  my @args = ( "bash", "-c", $cmd );
  print "command ".$cmd."\n";
  system(@args);
  if($? != 0){
    die "Command ".Dumper(@args)." failed";
  }
}
print "start";
systemBash("yes |head -n 1000000|awk '{print rand()}' > >(sort |gzip -9 -c > /dev/null)");
print "done";
```

Comment: Running "yes |head -n 1000000|awk '{print rand()}' > >(sort |gzip -9 -c > /dev/null)" in bash on my system results in an error. Try testing what you want to run in the shell first.

Comment: mxedeler, Runs fine from here.  madreblu, your code also seems to run fine from here.  What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: OmnipotentEntity: if you check the htop, you see that the sort + gzip are still running after the program print "done". I want the perl script to print done when everything is really done (all descendents are dead).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Perl wait for child processes started in the background with system()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911520/how-can-i-make-perl-wait-for-child-processes-started-in-the-background-with-syst)

Comment: A simple Google "perl wait for subprocess" would have given you the solution.

Comment: The problem is not waiting for the "main" subprocess. The problem is waiting for the children spawned by the child process.

Comment: Even modifying the systemBash command with a fork/exec/wait instead of using system() does not change the behavior.

Comment: I see, the issue with what you're trying to do, is you're redirecting your output to a piped function.  Because this doesn't rely on the standard stdout to stdin piping and instead uses a named pipe, the shell treats it as a different process family.  You don't need to use the `>()` construct in the example that you gave, you can just pipe it regularly; however, I think that you used this as just an example and the real problem you're trying to workout is different.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I know that I do not need a >() in the example I am giving you, it's a toy example of a bigger thing. I have a command with multiple >() and another reads the outputs produced as input at a later stage. However, it must wait until the "descandents" jobs are done. I think I can solve it using recursive "ps -o pid --ppid XXX" but that's ugly... isn't there a more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following hideous code to solve this problem:

```
sub findAllPIDs{
 my ($firstPID) = @_;
 my %hashPID;
 $hashPID{$firstPID}=1;
 my $found;
 do{
   $found=0;
   foreach my $key (keys %hashPID){
     my $cmd="ps -o pid --ppid ".$key;
     my $out=`$cmd`;
     foreach my $line (split("\n",$out)){
       $line =~ s/^\s+//;
       $line =~ s/\s+$//;
       if($line ne "PID"){
         if(!(exists $hashPID{$line})){
           $hashPID{$line}=1;
           $found=1;
         }
       }
     }
   }

 }while($found);
 return (keys %hashPID);
}

sub poll{
 my $proc=shift;
 while(1){
   my $cmd="ps  -o s --pid $proc";
   my $out=`$cmd`;
   my $found=0;
   my @arr=split("\n",$out);
   shift(@arr);
   foreach my $line (@arr){
     $line =~ s/^\s+//;
     $line =~ s/\s+$//;
     if($line ne "Z"  ){
       $found=1;
     }
   }
   if(!$found){
     return $proc;
   }
   sleep(2);
 }
}

sub systemBash {
 my $cmd = shift;
 my @args = ( "bash", "-c", $cmd );

 print "running ".$cmd."\n";
 if(!$fakeRun){
   my $pid=fork();
   if($pid == 0){
     exec(@args);
   }else{
     sleep(1);
     my @array=findAllPIDs($pid);
     foreach my $pid (@array){
       my $code =poll($pid);
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for Perl to wait on a process, it first needs to know the PID of the process it should wait for.

Because the child-processes in this example are spawned by the system (bash command), Perl is not aware of them, so there is no simple way to handle this, i.e.: you have to guess the PID of those child-processes.

I suggest you take one of two approaches: either you try to guess the PID of the last process in the chain and wait for it to end, or you break the sequence of events to single commands, each producing an output that is later "fed" to the next command
(this way you don't need to do any waiting at all - the 'system' command will do it for you).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to rework your approach or cheat.

Perl's `system()` waits for `bash`, which (as you know) waits for your pipeline to complete.  However, process substitution runs commands "divorced" from your `bash` child and its usual patience.  So:

### Rework your approach

1. Find a way to make the subprocesses a true pipeline, without process substitution.
2. Have the final processing stage signal perl via some sort of IPC (e.g., send a signal, write a byte, non-blocking, to a named pipe, etc.)

### Cheat

You can trick the children, grandchildren, etc. into effecting #2 above.

Let the children processes inherit the write end of a `pipe()`, closing your own copy of the write end after `system()` returns.  The read end will select readable when all descendants terminate.

You'll need to do some contortions to make that work, since [`pipe()`d filehandles are typically subject to `$^F`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pipe.html).  Something like:

```
use POSIX qw(F_SETFD);

...
  # XXX - error checking omitted
  pipe(my $rd, my $wr);
  fcntl($wr, F_SETFD, 0);

  system(...);
  close($wr);

  readline($rd); # Will block until all inherited copies of $wr are closed
```

This technique is hardly bullet-proof, but works often enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your process substitution into a FIFO, and explicitly wait for it to finish.

```
yes |head -n 1000000|awk '{print rand()}' > >(sort |gzip -9 -c > /dev/null)
```

Becomes

```
mkfifo tmp-fifo; { sort |gzip -9 -c > /dev/null; } < tmp-fifo & pid=$! ; yes |head -n 1000000|awk '{print rand()}' > tmp-fifo; wait $pid; rm tmp-fifo
```

The Perl code does not need to change.

Source: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-11/msg00137.html