# Python - call perl as subprocess - wait for finish its background process and print to shell

Tags: python, perl, subprocess

I have a Perl script, that inside calls `system("something &")`. If I run it from shell, I call the script and later use `wait` command to wait for all background processes.

How can I call this script from Python and wait for the "background" scripts it spawned to finish?

I have tried

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "script.pl", "data1", "data2"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.communicate()
```

but it wont wait and quits after the perl script finishes.

Another problem is I dont know how to print the output of background processes to shell while it is running.

Comment: You do what the shell does -- run the perl scripts in its own process group and then wait for the entire process group (by passing the negated pgid to wait or its python equivalent). I don't know much python, but [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP) seems to be a start. But notice that if the python itself is run from bash, the perl script and its children will be stopped or will get an errnor when they try to access the terminal. So many things may not work as expected.

Comment: That's why the shell itself does not do that by default when running a script. Notice that `perl -e "system q{sleep 60 &}"; wait` directly from the terminal will wait for the `sleep`, but `sh -c 'perl -e "system q{sleep 60 &}"; wait'` will **not**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fix this by changing the Perl script based on this answer [How can I make Perl wait for child processes started in the background with system()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911520/how-can-i-make-perl-wait-for-child-processes-started-in-the-background-with-syst)

I have changed

```
system("something &")
```

to

```
my $pid = fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
   print("Failed to fork");
   die;
} elsif ($pid == 0) {
   exec "something ";
}
```

and add

```
while (wait() != -1) {}
```

to the script end